What is the link syntax for returning the results of a wiki-internal search based on prepopulated search parameters?
I'm trying to find the Mediawiki link syntax for a wiki-internal search with pre-filled search parameters.
[[Special:Search]] is the syntax for a link that opens a Mediawiki search page where a user can manually enter a search string, however, instead of opening a search page, I want my link to already include the search string and immediately return the search results in one step.
I could use an external link approach like https://<wiki_instance>/index.php?title=<search_string>   but I'm looking for a solution that leverages the existing wiki link syntax [[...]].

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?

Keywords can be appended to the existing  [[Special:Search]] syntax separated by a slash /.
For example:
[[Special:Search/<keyword>]]

[[Special:Search/<keyword01> <keyword02>]]

Note: While a slash / must precede the keywords, subsequent slashes appear to be treated as literal characters (in case you structure your wiki with prefixes in that way).
While researching this solution I also found some search variations that can be adapted in the same way to repopulate search. For example, [[Special:LinkSearch]] opens the External links search page for user input but you can prepopulate the search for all http & https
links by adding a slash / and an asterisk *:
[[Special:LinkSearch/*]]        // all http/https (default)
[[Special:LinkSearch/http//*]]  // all HTTP

MediaWiki Resources:

Special:LinkSearch
Special:Search
Special pages
List of special pages

Linking special pages
You can link a special page as you would do for any other internal page; e.g. [[Special:Diff|see diff page]]. Some special pages can take a parameter value after a slash character; e.g. [[Special:Diff/6372234]] takes a user to the 6372234 revision ID of this page.source: Linking, transcluding, or redirecting to a special page
